# Perspective projection?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, graphics

I am trying to write an elite like game and I kind of understand the maths behind it but it would be really helpful if someone could explain it.

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on? [I think Wikipedia's explanation is pretty good.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_projection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link explains it way better than most could in a short answer here: http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/explaining-homogenous-coordinates-and-projective-geometry/

In summary:
4x4 matrices are used in graphics so that homogeneous coordinates (which are 4d) can be used.

This is important because it allows for both perspective and translation.

W is the fourth component of the vectors and can be seen as the distance between the projector and the surface that is being projected on.

To convert a 4d homogeneous vector to a 3d vector, you literally just divide X,Y and Z by the W component.

A neat side effect of this is that a vector with a W component of zero is a point at infinity in homogeneous coordinates.  This is why you sometimes see vectors described with a 0 in the W vector component, while points have a 1 in the W component.  This is most often seen when talking about point lights vs directional lights.  Directional lights are essentially point lights that are infinitely far away.

Also, to help understand how dividing X,Y,Z by W does projection, converting 3d coordinates to 2d screen coordinates can be done in a similar manner.  To convert from (X,Y,Z) to (X',Y') you just do this:

X' = X/Z
Y' = Y/Z

The fourth component (W) of the homogeneous coordinates performs the same role, to map 4d points in homogeneous coordinates to a 3d point that can then be converted to 2d and put on the screen.

Comment: You can still attempt to summarize the article so that the answer is not completely useless if the link goes away. If you feel that no answer can be made for the question at all, modify the question or vote to close it.